# Moose: Share attribute in role

Tags: perl, moose

i want to have an attribute declare in a Role and it's value to be shared between all instances of Classes that use the Role.

I have wrote this, but i don't think it's the better method to do it:

```
package RealRessource;
use Moose;
use MooseX::ClassAttribute;
class_has '_real_ressource' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Int', lazy => 1,
                                 builder => '_build_real_ressource' );

sub _build_real_ressource {
    print "_build_real_ressource\n";
    return int(rand(100));
}
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package ShareRessource;
use Moose::Role;
has 'ressource' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Int', lazy => 1,
                     builder => '_build_ressource' );

sub _build_ressource {
    print "Build New Ressource\n";
    my $real_ressource = new RealRessource();
    return $real_ressource->_real_ressource;
}

package A;
use Moose;

with 'ShareRessource';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package B;
use Moose;

with 'ShareRessource';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use A;
use B;

my $a = new A();
my $b = new B();
print $a->ressource,$/;
print $b->ressource,$/;
```

Result is:

```
Build New Ressource
_build_real_ressource
28
Build New Ressource
28
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does away with the extra RealResource class. The role was converted to a class so that it could share the class attribute. The use of [MooseX::ABC](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::ABC) is optional, but I put it there to enforce that it can't be instantiated.

```
package ShareResource;
use Moose;
use MooseX::ABC;
use MooseX::ClassAttribute;
class_has 'resource' => (
    is      => 'ro',
    isa     => 'Int',
    lazy    => 1,
    builder => '_build_resource',
);
sub _build_resource {
    print "_build_resource\n";
    return int(rand(100));
}
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package A;
use Moose;
extends 'ShareResource';
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package B;
use Moose;
extends 'ShareResource';
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use A;
use B;

my $a = A->new();
my $b = B->new();
print $a->resource,$/;
print $b->resource,$/;
```